# PHP exec ImageMagick not converting

Tags: php, image, pdf, imagemagick, exec

I am facing a weird issue by using the shell_exec function in my php script on my local env (mac os). I need to convert a pdf to images so I use the ImageMagick converter.

When I fire the command directly from my terminal, all is good:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert http://www.polyu.edu.hk/iaee/files/pdf-sample.pdf /www/sites/domain/public_html/test.jpg
```

When I fire this command (1:1) by the exec or shell_exec function in my script, there isn't happening so much as nothing. As a test I run the function:

```
Debug::dump(shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/convert -version"));

string 'Version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-01-08 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png tiff xml zlib
' (length=295)
```

This actually returns the version of ImageMagick, so this works fine. After this command I fire also a command through exec to count the pdf pages which goes fine as well.

```
$totalPages = exec("/usr/local/bin/pdfinfo " . $formData['upload']['tmp_name'] . " | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}'");

Debug::dump($totalPages);
string '18' (length=2)
```

**Test code in application returning 'null'**

```
var_dump(shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/convert http://www.polyu.edu.hk/iaee/files/pdf-sample.pdf /www/sites/domain/public_html/test.jpg'));
```

**apache error_log**

```
convert: no data returned `http://www.polyu.edu.hk/iaee/files/pdf-sample.pdf' @ error/url.c/ReadURLImage/264.
convert: no images defined `/www/sites/domain/public_html/test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3241.
```

**Update**

When running a php script from command line as $ php test.php it works fine.

Comment: Show the `exec` of the `convert` call in your PHP.

Comment: Are there any errors in your logs? Perhaps your webserver runs in a chroot and `/www/sites/.../test.jpg` is not writable.